# Gtk::SpinButton get_value_as_int gives step_increment as result

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I'm struggling with a SpinButton in Rust using Relm. (Disclaimer, I'm a noob with Rust **and** GTK)

```
#![feature(proc_macro)]
extern crate gtk;

use chrono::{NaiveTime, Duration};

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{
    WidgetExt,
    ContainerExt,
    EntryExt,
    Adjustment
};

use relm::Widget;
use relm_attributes::widget;

#[derive(Msg, Debug)]
pub enum Msg {
    Changed,
    Display,
}

#[widget]
impl Widget for DurationSpin {
    fn model(m: Duration) -> Duration {
        m
    }

    fn update(&mut self, event: Msg) {
        match event {
            Msg::Display => self.format_display(),
            Msg::Changed => {
                println!("update, self.spin_btn.get_value_as_int() = {:?}", self.spin_btn.get_value_as_int());
                self.model = Duration::minutes(self.spin_btn.get_value_as_int() as i64)

            },
        };
    }

    fn format_display(&mut self) {
        println!("format_display, self.spin_btn.get_value_as_int() = {:?}", self.spin_btn.get_value_as_int());
        let minus = self.model.num_hours() * 60;
        self.spin_btn.set_text(&format!("{:02}:{:02}",
                                        self.model.num_hours(), self.model.num_minutes() - minus));
    }

    view! {
        #[name="spin_btn"]
        gtk::SpinButton {
            max_width_chars: 5,
            width_chars: 5,
            max_length: 5,
            numeric: false,
            output => (Msg::Display, Inhibit(false)),
            value_changed => Msg::Changed,
            adjustment: &Adjustment::new(self.model.num_minutes() as f64, 0.0, 720.0, 1.0, 60.0, 0.0),
        }
    }
}
```

(whole project here: https://github.com/Geobert/rusty_flexi)

My issue is that clicking on "+" makes `get_value_as_int` always returns '1'.

It seems that my `output` signal is causing this as deactivating the connection solves the bug but I can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Try getting the value from the adjustment instead of from the spinbox. I think `get_value_as_int()` tries to reparse the text in the spinbox, though I'm not sure why that would always give you 1...

Comment: I tried `self.spin_btn.get_adjustment().get_value()` with no luck, still returning 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `output` signal handler must not be asynchronous. That means you should not use relm message passing in this case.

You should do something like:

```
fn init_view(&mut self) {
    let hours = self.model.num_hours();
    let minutes = self.model.num_minutes();
    self.spin_btn.connect_output(move |spin_btn| {
        let minus = hours * 60;
        spin_btn.set_text(&format!("{:02}:{:02}",
                                    hours, minutes - minus));
        Inhibit(false)
    });
}
```

and remove `output => (Msg::Display, Inhibit(false)),`